# Run code in separate output xterm like Code::Blocks in Visual Studio Code Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, codeblocks, xtermjs

Is possible to configure Visual Studio Code Terminal and run code in separate output xterm like Code::Blocks?
[image]

Code::Blocks use this command: `xterm -T $TITLE -e`

[image]

I tried to add this command in Visual Studio Code setting, but not work:

[image]